# How can I solve triple integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having a hard time solving this triple integral:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_y^x x e^{-z^2} \ dz\ dy\ dx$$

I tried doing u-substitution, but it repeated the same process as I solve.

Another thing I did was to find the new bounds for the whole integral, but I am not sure about it. I graph the original bounds to get the new bounds. The new bounds that I got was this:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x e^{-z^2} \ dz\ dy\ dx$$

I came up with this because the bounds for z is z=y and z=x, so I substitute the values for x and y to z. But did I do it correctly?

Comment: @TeM there was a mistake for bounds in z, my bad. Its y < z < x. But is it still the same?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you have $y \leqslant x$, rewrite,
$$
I = -\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_y^x xe^{-z^2} \, dzdydx
$$

If you want correctly to get bounds that always equal $[0,1]$, you have to introduce indicator functions like you example $1_{x \leqslant y}(x,y) = 1$ if $x \leqslant y$, $0$ else (you get how it works). You integral is,
$$
I = -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{-z^2} 1_{y \leqslant z \leqslant x}(x,y,z)\, dzdydx
$$
Now, you can use Fubini-Tonelli to exchange the integrals and get rid of this annoying $e^{-z^2}$ that has no common primitive,
\begin{align*}
I & = -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{-z^2} 1_{y \leqslant z \leqslant x}(x,y,z)\, dzdydx\\
& = -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{-z^2} 1_{y \leqslant z \leqslant x}(x,y,z)\, dxdydz\\
& = -\int_0^1 \int_0^z \int_z^1 xe^{-z^2} \, dxdydz
\end{align*}
In other words, $z$ goes from $0$ to $1$, then $y$ must stay under $z$, so it goes from $0$ to $z$ and finally, $x$ must stay over $z$ so it goes from $z$ to $1$. An other way to see it is to consider your integral as a $3$-dimensional integral in the domain $\Delta = \{(x,y,z), 0 \leqslant y \leqslant z \leqslant x \leqslant 1\}$.
\begin{align*}
I & = -\int_0^1 \int_0^z \int_z^1 xe^{-z^2} \, dxdydz\\
& = -\int_0^1 \int_0^z \frac{1 - z^2}{2}e^{-z^2} \, dydz\\
& = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 z(1 - z^2)e^{-z^2} \, dz\\
\end{align*}
Now, do an integration by parts with $u'(z) = ze^{-z^2}$ and $v(z) = 1 - z^2$ and you should get your answer !

Answer (score 1):

The sections of the domain with respect to planes $x=x_0$ are triangles with boundaries $y=0$, $z=x_0$ and $z=y$, therefore

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_y^x x e^{-z^2} \ dz\ dy\ dx=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{x}dz\int_{0}^{z}x e^{-z^2}dy=\int_{0}^{1}xdx\int_{0}^{x}z e^{-z^2}dz=$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}x \left[-\frac12e^{-z^2}\right]_0^xdx=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}x-xe^{-x^2} dx =\frac12\left[\frac12x^2+\frac12e^{-x^2}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{4e}$$

[image]